# Write a Python program to print all prime numbers in an interval?

Tags: python, primes

Define a function that takes two integers (start, end) and classify the numbers between the range as prime and non-prime number and print the prime numbers

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 1: 
        return False 
    for i in range(2, n+1): 
        if n % i == 0: 
            return False 
    return True 
 
def print_primes(start, end): 
    for i in range(start, end): 
        if is_prime(i): 
            print(i) 
 
a=int(input("Start value: ")
b=int(input("End value: ")
print_primes(a,b)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some bugs which are fixed.**

(1) you have not closed round parameter while taking input from the user `a` and `b`

(2) `is_prime()`. for loop run till `n-1` not till the `n`

(3) stored answer in res for the readability.

**Code:-**

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 1: 
        return False 
    for i in range(2, n): 
        if n % i == 0: 
            return False 
    return True 
 
def print_primes(start, end):
    res=[]
    for i in range(start, end): 
        if is_prime(i): 
            res.append(i)
    return res
 
a=int(input("Start value: "))
b=int(input("End value: "))
print(print_primes(a,b))
```

**Output:**

```
Start value: 3
End value: 13
[3, 5, 7, 11]
```

As you can see start value is inclusive and end value is exclusive to make both inclusive just iterated to `end+1` in `print_primes` function

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 1: 
        return False 
    for i in range(2, n+1):
```

It should be:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n < 1: 
        return False 
    for i in range(2, n):
```

It should go till less than n, else `n` will always be divisible by `i` and return `False`

```
a=int(input("Start value:"))  # make sure to close the parenthesis
b=int(input("End value:"))    # make sure to close the parenthesis
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def is_prime(n): 
    if n < 2: 
        return False 
    for i in range(2, n): 
        if n % i == 0: 
            return False 
    return True 
 
def print_primes(start, end): 
    for i in range(start, end+1): 
        if is_prime(i): 
            print(i) 
 
a=int(input("Start value:")
b=int(input("End value:")
print_primes(a,b)
```

Comment: will give `error: Syntax error`

Answer (score -2):

This takes into account the problem of float in range. Try it. :)

```
def is_prime(n):    
    if not n < 1:      
        for i in range(2, n): 
            if not n % i == 0:
                return True
            else:
                return False

    
def print_primes(start, end):
    res=[]
    start=int(start)
    end=int(end)
    for i in range(start, end+1):
        if is_prime(i): 
            res.append(i)
    return res
    
#a=int(input("Start value: "))
#b=int(input("End value: "))
a=0.3
b=41
print_primes(a,b) 
#[3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33, 35, 37, 39, 41]
```